# Trying to display file uploader error message on hover, rather than upon dropping the file (as it is right now)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drag and drop file uploader (well it looks like a file uploader but just converts the images you choose into base64 and displays them as thumbnails).

https://jsfiddle.net/jgze6hwv/41/

I have an error message display once the file is dropped or chosen in the file browser, but I am trying to display the error message when the file is hovered over the drop zone, even before it's actually released. The error will display if the file you're trying to use is anything other than .jpg/.jpeg.

The error html was built into the const for generating the image container/thumbnails, so I just made a second const with just the bit for the error message. I wasn't sure if I needed to change anything in this since it was just going to display on over and not actually after the file is dropped.

```
const fileHandler2 = (file, name, type) => {
  if (type.split("/")[1] !== "jpeg") {
    //File Type Error
    container.classList.remove("dropped");
    submit.classList.remove("hideit");
    error.innerHTML = "Error message HTML removed to save space in this post";
    error.classList.remove("hideit");
    return false;
  };
```

I tried various ways of adding it to the dragenter and dragover events but could never get the syntax right.

```
container.addEventListener(
  "dragenter", 
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.add("active");
  },
  false
);


container.addEventListener(
  "dragover",
     (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.add("active");
  },
  false
);
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```js
container.addEventListener(
  "dragenter",
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const img = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items).find(e => e.type.includes('image'))
    if (img) container.classList.add("active");
    else {} // show error
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. I appreciate you taking the time to do that.. I'm still learning, I'm not sure I ever would have reached that solution without help.

Cheers